# How do I combine grep with multiple arguments and different output switches

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to grep with multiple arguments where i want to show lines in the order they appear in my source file before one argument and lines after the other argument , i e combine:

```
grep -A5 onestring foo.txt
```

and

```
grep -B5 otherstring foo.txt
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Run grep twice.

Comment: Yes but then I dont know the order between the matches. I am looking at at log at want to see what happens before otherstring and after onestring. So the order is highly relevant.

Comment: Hmm. `( grep -nA5 onestring foo.txt; grep -nB5 onestring foo.txt ) | sort -gu` then. (Run grep twice with line numbers and uniquely sort them)

Comment: Good idea. But will this work if I want to do this with multiple files?

Comment: We can ask grep to print filenames additionally or write a shell-function with some for loops.

Comment: Actually if I add the file names to grep output with the switch -H this gives me the exact output that I wanted.

Comment: Updated my answer. @cas gave me a nice hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, ksh or zsh:

```
sort -gum <(grep -nA5 onestring foo.txt) <(grep -nB5 otherstring foo.txt)
# Sort by general numbers, make output unique and merge sorted files,
# where files are expanded as a result of shell's command expansion,
# FIFOs/FDs that gives the command's output
```

This takes O(*n*) time, given that `grep` outputs already sorted things. If process substitution is unavailable, either create temp files manually or use the O(*n* lg*n*) `( grep -nA5 onestring foo.txt; grep -nB5 otherstring foo.txt ) | sort -gu`.

With `grep -H` we need to sort it in a more verbose way (thanks to cas):

```
# FIXME: I need to figure out how to deal with : in filenames then.
# Use : as separator, the first field using the default alphabetical sort, and
# 2nd field using general number sort.
sort -t: -f1,2g -um <(grep -nA5 onestring foo.txt bar.txt) <(grep -nB5 otherstring foo.txt bar.txt)
```

Comment: grep's output isn't sorted, rather the log file input is pre-sorted by date and time.  i assume that's what you meant, but the way you wrote it isn't right.

Comment: @cas They are, in the sense of line numbers. We are using `sort` to put the lines back into the original order.

Comment: btw, when using `grep -H` you can use `sort`'s `-t:` and `-k` options to skip sorting on the filename etc fields.

Comment: right, so you are. missed that, my mistake